# How to adjust Select query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to eliminate the result of the Select statement
if a certain amount of numbers appear at the end.

Example:

```
select name from table where registration = '1234'
```

if the data record is:

> Joe Bin12345

I need the result to lose its registration number when printing:

```
Joe Bin
```

The result should loose its digits
only if it contains five numeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT name,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '[0-9]{5}$', '') cleared
FROM test;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b48024f18cde41df3872ed2e6c6091e3)